Upper bound of central probability of a binomial variable
Given an integer $k \geq 0$, if random variable satisfies the following condition:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X = i\right) = \frac{\binom{k}{i}}{2^{k}},
\quad i \in \left\lbrace 0,1,\ldots,k\right\rbrace
$$
Then we have the following holds for any positive integer $a$:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\left\vert X - \frac{k}{2}\right\vert \leq \frac{a}{2}\right) < 2a\,\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi k}}
$$
How do we prove the lemma 3 in this paper? Thanks in advance for any help!

What's your question?

The probability should also be given this way for $i=0$. Otherwise this won't be a probability distribution.

I would interpret the RHS as $+\infty$ when $k=0$.

Here's an approach for which I haven't checked whether it works in the end: We may write $\mathbb P(\lvert X-\frac{k}{2}\rvert \leq \frac{a}{2}) = \mathbb P(k-a\leq 2X\leq k+a) = \sum_{j=k-a}^{k+a} \mathbb P(2X=j)$. Once it is shown that $\mathbb P(2X=j) < \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi k}}$ your inequality follows. For this estimate I would probably use some Stirling-type inequality. Probably Zack Fisher answer does that.

Do you mind explain when this inequality is useful? I usually see tail probability bounds, not the central ones.

I pay significant attention to this lemma because the stability of k-nearest neighbors regarding the binomial distribution can help me understand the proof of the conclusion on the β-hypothesis stability with sample replacement in the binary classification sample space. @ZackFisher

We may use Stirling's approximation
$$\sqrt{2 \pi n}\ 
\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\left(\frac{1}{12n} - \frac{1}{360n^3}\right)} < n! < \sqrt{2 \pi n}\ \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n e^{\frac{1}{12n}}
$$
to approximate the probability at the mode of the binomial distribution to prove this inequality.
The main idea is to multiply the "highest probability" at the mode by the "number of points" in the event to provide an upper bound of the event probability.

For even $k=2n$, the mode is located at $n$, with probability,
$$\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2 2^{2n}} 
<\frac{\sqrt{2\pi\cdot2n}\cdot  (2n)^{2n} e^{-2n}}
{2\pi n\cdot n^{2n} e^{-2n} \cdot 2^{2n} } C_1
= \frac1{\sqrt{\pi n}} C_1 < \sqrt{\frac2{\pi k}},  \tag{1e}\label{1e}
$$
where the positive factor $C_1$ is $$
C_1=\exp{\left\lbrace \frac{1}{4n}\left( \frac{1}{45n^2}-\frac12 \right) \right\rbrace} < 1. 
$$
The event $\left\lvert X-\frac{k}2 \right\rvert \leq \frac{a}2$ includes the central $$
2\lceil (a+1)/2 \rceil -1\leq 2a \tag{2e}\label{2e}
$$
points in the support of the binomial distribution (i.e., in the set $\lbrace 0,1,2,\dots,k \rbrace$).

For odd $k=2n+1$, the modes are located at $n$ and $n+1$, with probability
$$\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!(n+1)! 2^{2n+1}}
=\frac{2n+1}{2n+2} \cdot \frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2 2^{2n}}
<\frac{2n+1}{2n+2} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi n}}=\frac{k}{k+1}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi(k-1)}}, 
$$ where the inequality is due to $\eqref{1e}$.
For the RHS to be  $<\sqrt{2/(\pi k)}$, we need
$$k^2-k-1>0\ \text{or}\ k > \phi\approx 1.618. 
$$This holds for all odd $k\geq3$. But when $k=1$, trivially $\sqrt{2/(\pi k)}>0.79>0.5$, the latter being the LHS mode probability. Therefore, for all odd $k\geq1$, the mode probability $$
\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!(n+1)! 2^{2n+1}} < \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi k}}. \tag{1o}\label{1o}
$$
In this case, the event $\left\lvert X-\frac{k}2 \right\rvert \leq \frac{a}2$ includes the central
$$
2\lceil a/2 \rceil \leq 2a \tag{2o}\label{2o}
$$ points in the support of the binomial distribution.


Therefore, in both cases, the probability of interest is bounded above by multiplying $\eqref{1e}$ with $\eqref{2e}$, or by multiplying $\eqref{1o}$ with $\eqref{2o}$, respectively, giving the RHS of the inequality $$2a  \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi k}}.$$

I am a bit confused. "For even $k=2n$, the mode of the binomial distribution $B(2n, 1/2)$ is located at $n$." Then why do you consider only the probability of exactly $n$ successes rather than the probabilities of having $n, n + 1, \cdots, 2n$ successes altogether?

By definition of mode, this is the point with highest probability. Other points have lower probability. Thus, the "highest prob" multiplied by the "number of points" provides an upper bound.

“The event $∣∣−/2∣∣≤/2$ includes the central $2⌈(+1)/2⌉−1≤2$ points in support of the binomial distribution.” What does this sentence mean?

@JimmyZhao Plot the pmf for the binomial. For $a=1,2,3,4,5,...$, the event include  1,3,3,5,5,... spikes in the plot, starting from the center (mode). For $a=1$, only the mode itself is included; for $a=2$, two adjacent spikes are included, etc.

I think you cannot directly use (1e)'s conclusion for (1o), since $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi k}}$ is different for $k = 2n$ and $k = 2n + 1$.

@JimmyZhao Yeah. That's my fault. Then we'll probably have to work on the messy Stirling again...

@JimmyZhao Actually, I don't need to rework on the Stirling approximation. It's fixed now.

By the way, it seems the bound in the lemma is not tight. This means the left-hand side (LHS) still holds if the right-hand side (RHS) is $a\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi k}}$?

@JimmyZhao Definitely not tight---it's $<$, not $\leq$. But removing factor $2$ is too aggressive for small $a$, e.g., when $k=7$ and $a=1$. The Stirling part is fairly close, but the part on the number of points has plenty of room for improvement, esp. if $a$ gets larger. The RHS may be >1. But any improvement probably sacrifices some simplicity.

"But removing factor 2 is too aggressive for small , e.g., when =7 and =1 ." However, removing factor 2 makes the inequality still hold, right?

@JimmyZhao No. For $k=7$ and $a=1$, the prob is $>0.546$, but the RHS is $<0.302$.

Ok, but this is so weird since we have proved $1o$, then $2e$ and $2o$ should make sense for the $a$ scale (rather than $2a$), why is it not?

@JimmyZhao Just check (2o) for $a=1$: it's 2=2.

This inequality does not always hold, unless some restrictions are imposed on $a$ and/or on $k$.
Trivially, if $k>0$ is even and $a=0$, then $$P\left(\left\lvert X-\frac{k}2\right\rvert\leq\frac02\right)=P\left(X=\frac{k}2\right)>0,\text{ but RHS}=0.$$
Even if $a>0$ is imposed, with small enough $a$ and an even $k$, the LHS is still a positive constant, $$P\left(X=\frac{k}2\right)>0.$$But, given $k$, the RHS is linearly increasing with $a$.  So it is always possible to choose a small enough value of $a$ to make the RHS smaller than the LHS.
If $a\geq1$, then for $k=1,2$, the RHS is $>1$ and the inequality is trivially true.

Imposing integer $a\ge 5$ condition
In this case, we can use Berry-Esseen bound (which was also used in your reference) on central limit theorem to verify the inequality.
Let $Y=\frac{X-\tfrac{k}2}{\tfrac{\sqrt{k}}{2}}$, which is approximately standard normal. Denote its cumulative distribution function as $F$, and the standard normal distribution function as $\Phi$.
$$
P\left( \left\lvert X-\frac{k}2 \right\rvert \leq \frac{a}2 \right)
=P\left(-\frac{a}{\sqrt{k}}\leq Y \leq \frac{a}{\sqrt{k}} \right)
\leq F\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{k}}\right) - F\left(-\frac{a}{\sqrt{k}}-\epsilon\right)
$$
for a sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$.
With the Berry-Esseen bound, $$
\left\lvert F(y)-\Phi(y)\right\rvert \leq \frac{4C}{\sqrt{k}}
$$
where $C<0.4748$,
the LHS probability is
$$
< 2\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{k}}+\epsilon\right) -1 +\frac{8C}{\sqrt{k}}.
$$
But for any $y>0$, a simple linear upper bound for $\Phi(y)$ is $$\Phi(y)<\frac12+\frac{y}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.$$
Therefore, the LHS probability is
$$
<\sqrt{\frac2{\pi}} \left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{k}}+\epsilon\right)+\frac{8C}{\sqrt{k}}.
$$
For this to be $<2a\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi k}}$, all we need is
$$
a > 4\sqrt{2\pi}C +\sqrt{k}\epsilon > 4.76 +\sqrt{k}\epsilon.
$$
By choosing a sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$, this is satisfied when integer $a\geq5$.

@JimmyZhao So far, I only worked out the case when $a\geq5$ and have updated the response.

what if $a = 1,2,3,4$? Is that possible to prove it?

The proof covering all $a>0$ is given in the other post. I kept this post only because you mentioned the reference that used Berry-Esseen, in case that you are interested in it.
